# Не запускается ProgressDialog перед new Thread

Tags: android, progress-bar, android-threads

Пока последовательно загружается инфа на сервер хочу отрисовать ProgressDialog, но вся активность залипает до окончания работы всех потоков.

```
 private void uploadImageSync() {
        final ProgressDialog progressDialog;
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(BarcodActivity.this);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Загрузка фото...");
        progressDialog.show();

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(ROOT_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        RequestInterface service = retrofit.create(RequestInterface.class);

        int i=0;
        while (i++ <= 4) {
            File f = getOutputMediaFilePath(mCode + "_"+i, true);
            if(f.exists()){
                RequestBody requestFile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), f);

                MultipartBody.Part body = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("file", f.getName(), requestFile);

                final Call<ResponseBody> resultCall = service.uploadImage(body);

                Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            ResponseBody r = resultCall.execute().body();
                            Log.d("MyLog", "загружен");
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }});
                t.start();
                try {
                    t.join();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        progressDialog.dismiss();
    }
```

Comment: Почему вы не пользуетесь интерфейсом Call от ретрофита?

Comment: Да я пока особо не разобрался в возможностях retrofit. А разве это не он `Call<ResponseBody>`

Comment: Он, но вы запрос не через него делаете

Comment: Хм...а это что в потоке? `resultCall.execute().body();`

Comment: Своим `t.join();` вы заблокировали текущий поток (в данном случае UI-поток) на время, пока каждый из потоков в цикле не умрет. Либо цикл надо переместить внутрь потока, либо как правильно подсказывают: в `onResponse()` запускать следующий запрос. Кроме того, multipart'ом нельзя слать сразу все файлы?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так

```
 Call<ResponseBody> result = service.uploadImage(body);
    result.enqueue(new Callback<Object>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<Object> response) {
            progressDialog.hide();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Object> call, Throwable t) {
            progressDialog.hide();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Это ансинхронный. А мне надо последовательно выполнить несколько запросов

Comment: Ну так можно же на onResponse запустить следующий запрос

Comment: Делать рекурсию...была у меня такая идея... но показалось что много мороки. Текущий вариант мне показался проще. Если не учитывать проблемы с `ProgressDialog `

Comment: @BogdanShulga в текущем варианте вы не решите проблему с диалогом